# Printing PDF on iOS, background image not printing

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, cordova

I'm attempting to print a PDF file in my Cordova application on iOS.

The file is generated using [jsPDF](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf) in the Cordova app and then I've modified the [katzer cordova-plugin-printer](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer) to accept the raw PDF data as a string, convert it to NSData and print it out.

```
- (void) printPDFFromData:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    if (!self.isPrintingAvailable)
    {
        return;
    }

    NSArray*  arguments = [command arguments];
    NSString* documentData = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    NSData* pdfData = [documentData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    UIPrintInteractionController* controller = printController;

    [self adjustSettingsForPrintController:controller];
    controller.printingItem = pdfData;

    [self openPrintController:controller];

    [self commandDelegate];
}
```

Using the iOS print simulator (I don't have access to an AirPrint printer), the PDF appears to print out, except that the background image is not printed, just the vector drawings overlaying it.

The same raw output data when saved to a PDF file will display the background image and when you print that file, the background image is printed.

Is this just an anomaly of the printer simulator or do I need to somehow set the print controller to be able to print the image in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the issue. Something was getting lost in the decoding of the string data from JavaScript into Objective-C.

To get around this I Base64 encoded the PDF document in my JS side before sending it off to the plugin:

```
var startIndexOfBase64Data = 28;
var base64Document = doc.output('dataurlstring').substring(startIndexOfBase64Data);
window.plugin.printer.printPDFFromData(base64Document);
```

Then I needed to add

> NSData+Base64.m and NSData+Base64.h

from [this sample project](http://projectswithlove.com/projects/NSData_Base64.zip) into my plugins directory to allow this line of code to convert the Base64 string into NSData:

```
NSData* pdfData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:documentData];
```

Then the document then printed out untainted.

Now I'm off to see if I can get it working with Android.

Comment: I am also needing to print raw base64 pdf data from a PhoneGap app (iOS) -- do you by chance have a public fork of the modified katzer plugin that you used?